# How to create Exception in Recurrence with Outlook REST API

Tags: rest, office365, recurrence, outlook-restapi

We can create recurring Events using Outlook REST API by defining PatternedRecurrence with OutlookServices.RecurrencePattern and OutlookServices.RecurrenceRange.

But how to define Exceptions using REST API? 
Is creating new Event of Type 'Exception' and SeriesMasterId as the ID of Series Master enough to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is creating new Event of Type 'Exception' and SeriesMasterId as the ID of Series Master enough to achieve this?

No, it will not work like that. After waiting for an answer and trying it ourselves we discovered that this will create a new Event in Calendar and we will end up with 2 events on the same date. Not the desired result, right?

To create Exception in Recurrence we have to get the ID of the Instance/Occurrence that needs to be modified. This can be done by getting all instances from Master event on the date of exception.

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

Then change the TYPE property to EXCEPTION, set desired changes and update this event using PATCH on Rest API.